# Determining if a number is a factorial

Tags: java, factorial

I have to write a method that indicates if a number is a factorial of a number. Basically whatever number the user inputs, the method should be able to tell if that number (x) is a factorial of another number. I've written a method that finds the factorial of (x), but I need to know if (x) is a factorial of another number. I've been using 6 as an example for now since 6 is the factorial of 3. Any suggestions?

```
public static int Fact(int x) {
    int y=1;
    while(x>1) {
        y=y*x;
        x=x-1;
    }
    return y; 
}
```

Comment: you can use the mod operator

Comment: The number of factorials representable as a 32bit int is small enough that you should just use a lookup table.

Comment: This defo a home work . Better ask your teacher.

Comment: If i could ask my teacher i would of asked, all im asking for is advice,not the answer.

Comment: My advice is simple: work hard to discover how to resolve this 1st year of computer science issue. This is a Q&A page, but the A is not intended to be for "advice", but for "answers". If you cannot do this by your own, got bad news for you.

Answer (score 2):

A factorial is of the form `(1) * 2 * 3 * 4...`, So I'd just start multiplying those numbers until you either reach or overshoot your number.

It should be quite simple.

Comment: there would be a lot of combinations to go through.

Comment: @JohnKane let me ask you, is `6` a factor of `3` or is `6` the factorial of `3` or `3!`

Comment: @JohnKane I thought that he might be asking for factors at first too, but then I more closely examined the example he gave

Comment: @JohnKane The worst case is that x=Integer.MAX_VALUE.  Even in that case, there won't be that many combinations to go through.

Comment: I think this is a very good solution, I tried it, it is fast.

Comment: I was picturing the user was trying to find a factor of the number you were given. For example, if you are given 15 you would have to go through every possible value for two before getting to 3. Unless I am looking at your approach wrong.

Comment: @JohnKane **factorIAL**, not factor

Answer (score 1):

> As fact n = 1*2*3*4*..n , (n%i)==0 should always be true for i in [1,n]

This should work fine

```
public class Factorial {

    public static boolean isFactorial(int x){
        int i =x;
        boolean bol = false;

        for ( i=2 ; i<x ; i++ ) {
            if ((x%i)==0) bol = true ;
            else bol = false ;break;
        }
        return bol;         
    }    
}
```

And you can test it with this class :

```
public class TestFact {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        System.out.println(Factorial.isFactorial(120));
    }    
}
```

Comment: What im getting out of this is that it returns if the number inputted (x) is a factorial or not?

Comment: Yes for example `Factorial.isfactorial(120)` would return true because 120 is the factorial of 5 ; Is that what you needed ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [the mod](http://www.cafeaulait.org/course/week2/15.html) operator. If the number mod some other number = 0 then you have found a factor. (Assuming this is what you are looking for). For example:

```
public static int Fact(int x){
    int i=2;
        while(x % i (has no remainder) || (stop criteria))
            i++;//increment the number

    if(x!=i)//you found a factor
        return i;

    return -1; 
}
```

Comment: You should stop when i > sqrt(x).

Comment: I agree, I just didnt want to give too much away. I felt bad giving away this much.